# How to get Vector data in skeletonization?

Tags: opencv

i am using opencv to track the edge of a hand on an image. Using skin color is not that reliable so we can't use contour. Using Canny edge detection match what we need because it can get most of the outline correctly. Now i want to make the information to vector so that i can improve it in the vector way. I can't use HoughLinesP because the lines are usually not straight. Dilating it gives lots of unwant random lines. I can do thinning but i don't know what next step i should do. the thinned image is still image. I need the vector data. So how do i do it?

[image: A pic showing the concept]

Comment: Can you attach your thinned image ?